# iPad master detail app - change detail view controller's content

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I started to explore the UISplitViewController class with a new master detail project in XCode, and I would like to replace the detail view's content with another UIViewControllers. I wrote it in this way (self is the detail viewcontroller and controller is the uiviewcontroller which I want to replace the first one with):

```
self.view = controller.view;
```

My question is: is it a proper way, will Apple accept it? If it is not, how could I do it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also building an iPad app with Master - Detail View Controllers in a UIIntelligentSplitViewController. As UISplitViewController doesn't support well while changing to different orientations, using UIIntelligentSplitViewController solves the issue with orientation change. See more [here](https://github.com/grgcombs/IntelligentSplitViewController).

I have read on one of apple documentation and also a in best practices that we should use Only one MasterView and DetailView Controllers in entire app, and write code in such a way that all data are loaded in these two views according to the object selected.

But loading all data in same detail view might be a lot of code. So, I am also in search for answer for efficiently writing code to load in same detail view controller. However currently I am implementing only two views to show net data.

If there is any other efficient way to accomplish it, please do mention. Thanks.

Comment: As My iPad App is growing big, I have come with separate detail view controllers. Using separate Detail View Controllers helped me a lot to make my code more readable. Code are separate for separate view and it was easier to do checking and loading in detail View as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the detail view controller where it is setup in your app delegate "didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsMethod". Your method would probably also work but is creating unnecessary overhead. The auto generated code they provide default's to a navigation controller on the left and a view controller on the right but you can change that to whatever you need. I have a project where I have two navigation controllers.